# Слетели компоненты в Angular

Tags: angular

Учебный проект на Angular 11
После добавления в проект окна диалога у меня появилась следующая ошибка:

```
Error: src/app/app.component.html:3:1 - error NG8001: 'ng-sidebar-container' is not a known element:
1. If 'ng-sidebar-container' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ng-sidebar-container' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
```

До этого ее не было.
Я удалил папку node_modules. Выполнил

```
npm install
```

После чего у меня уже перестали видеться уже несколько компонентов:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {MatDialogModule} from '@angular/material/dialog';
```

Ошибка :

```
TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/platform-browser' or its corresponding type declarations.
TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core' or its corresponding type declarations.
TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/common/http' or its corresponding type declarations.
TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/forms' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

Я стал их уже устанавливать по одному

```
npm i --save @angular/material@11.0.7
...
```

Но ошибка не уходит. Я уже пошел их устанавливать по второму кругу, но чет не помогает.
Я так понимаю где-то идет конфликт версий.

Как в этом Angular понять какие версии компонентов дружат друг с другом?
И как мне выбраться из этого замкнутого круга?

Вот что у меня установлено на данный момент:

```
Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1100.7
@angular-devkit/build-angular   0.1100.7
@angular-devkit/core            11.0.7
@angular-devkit/schematics      11.0.7
@angular/animations             11.0.7
@angular/cdk                    11.2.7
@angular/cli                    11.0.7
@angular/material               11.0.4
@schematics/angular             11.0.7
@schematics/update              0.1100.7
rxjs                            6.6.7
typescript                      4.0.7
```

Еще при установки выдает такие предупреждения:

```
npm WARN @angular/animations@11.0.7 requires a peer of @angular/core@11.0.7 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/material@11.0.4 requires a peer of @angular/cdk@11.0.4 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.3.2 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\watchpack-chokidar2\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.3 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
```

Но они и раньше были, и все работало.

Comment: Вообще надо смотреть первую строчку ошибки, где написано:
Error: src/app/app.component.html:3:1 - error NG8001: 'ng-sidebar-container' is not a known element:


Очевидно в module.ts где идут декларации модулей, компонентов и импортов, не продекларирован этот компонент ng-sidebar-container

Answer (score 1):

Проблема оказалась в самой IDEA. На зарубежном форуме нашел похожий вопрос. Оказалось, что IDEA при добавлении новых компонентов (точно не могу перевести), но что-то там блокирует. Это происходит редко, но такое бывает. Меня сбило с толку, что перестал видеться компонент, который до этого прекрасно работал.
Проблема решилась перезагрузкой самой IDEA.
Возможно есть какое-то решение этой проблемы, типа какие-то настройки прописать в самой IDE, но я такого не нашел.